# Dynamic routing with react-roter-dom v6 problem

Tags: react-router-dom

I am trying to link up a component by a button in another component. I tried this way.

in app.js file

```
<Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />}>
    <Route path=":id" element={<SingleProject />} />
</Route>
```

and in the portfolio component,

```
<Link to={`/portfolio/${dt.id}`} className="text-2xl text-red-100 borde border-coral px-2 block text-center"><i class="fas fa-info-circle" title="Details"></i></Link>
```

But unfortunately it's not working! every time I clicked on the button, it show me the portfolio component. not specific dynamic page. which should be loaded. How can I fix the problem?

Comment: When the routes are wrapped like this the `Portfolio` component is treated as a layout/wrapper component and is still rendered when nested routes match. Are you wanting to display both the `Portfolio` and `SingleProject` components at the same time or only one or the other?

Comment: @DrewReese I want to render only one. In Portfolio component I have displayed a few projects of mine. and added a button for details. by clicking which user will be redirected to the details page of the specific project he/she clicked.

Answer (score 4):

When the routes are wrapped like this the `Portfolio` component is treated as a layout/wrapper component and is still rendered when nested routes match. Since you want to render each independently on their own routes they can't be nested. Move the `SingleProject` out to its own route.

```
<Route path="/portfolio" element={<Portfolio />} />
<Route path="/portfolio/:id" element={<SingleProject />} />
```

If these components happen to share a layout or you do want to nest the routes then create a layout wrapper component that renders an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PortfolioLayout = () => {
  return <Outlet />;
};
```

...

```
<Route path="/portfolio" element={<PortfolioLayout />}>
  <Route index element={<Portfolio />} />
  <Route path=":id" element={<SingleProject />} />
</Route>
```

If you like, in RRDv6 you can also use relative links (i.e. links don't start with a `"/"` character) so if `Portfolio` is rendering the link it can relatively link to `":id"`.

```
<Link
  to={`${dt.id}`}
  className="...."
>
  <i class="fas fa-info-circle" title="Details" />
</Link>
```